# Returning values in async functions - Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Using Cloud Firestore as my DB.
I need to read data from two separate documents in my code, get data from a document based on value in the previous document.

Getting data from firestore in a Future method which looks like this:

```
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getGenAlertsData() async{

  QuerySnapshot alertRef = await Firestore.instance.collection('alerts').orderBy('time', descending: true).getDocuments();

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> messages = new List();
  Map<String, dynamic> fullMessage;

// int counter = 0;

  alertRef.documents.forEach((doc) async {
    // counter++;
    String senderKey, senderNameKey, senderSpecKey, senderPicKey, msgBodyKey, timeKey, sender, senderName, senderSpec, msgBody, senderPic;
    senderKey = 'sender';
    sender = doc['sender'];
    timeKey = 'time';
    DateTime time = doc['time'];
    print(time);
    msgBodyKey = 'msgBody';
    msgBody = doc['msgBody'];
    DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.document('/staff/'+sender);
    print(ref.documentID);

    await ref.get().then((onValue) { //values not populated here :(
      senderNameKey = 'senderName';
      senderName =  onValue['name'];
      print(senderName);
      senderPicKey = 'senderPic';
      senderPic =   onValue['profilePic'];
      senderSpecKey = 'specialization';
      senderSpec =  onValue['specialization'];
    });

    // await print(senderName);
    fullMessage = <String, dynamic> {
      senderKey: sender,
      senderNameKey: senderName,
      senderSpecKey: senderSpec,
      senderPicKey: senderPic,
      timeKey: time,
      msgBodyKey: msgBody,
    };


    messages.add(fullMessage);

    print(messages.toString()); // I get the messages printed in my console here

  }); //loop over collection ends here

  print(messages.toString()); // No data here :(

    return messages;

}
```

At this point only the values from `alertRef.documents.forEach((doc)` are avaialble, and the values inside `await ref.get().then((onValue) {` are not populated (they are null in the `fullMessage` Map) .

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yaay! Figured it out finally!

Apparently, then() doesn't work that well inside async functions, now my code looks like this, and everything's great now! :)

Put it all in a good old for loop and everything''s fine now.

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getGenAlertsData() async{

  QuerySnapshot alertRef = await Firestore.instance.collection('alerts').orderBy('time', descending: true).getDocuments();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> messages = new List();
  Map<String, dynamic> fullMessage;
  // String xxx;

  String senderKey, senderNameKey, senderSpecKey, senderPicKey, msgBodyKey, timeKey, sender, senderName, senderSpec, msgBody, senderPic;


  List<DocumentSnapshot> alertSnaps= alertRef.documents;

  for (int i = 0; i < alertSnaps.length; i++)

  {
    senderKey = 'sender';
    sender = alertSnaps[i]['sender'];
    timeKey = 'time';
    DateTime time = alertSnaps[i]['time'];
    print(time);
    msgBodyKey = 'msgBody';
    msgBody = alertSnaps[i]['msgBody'];
    DocumentSnapshot snappy = await Firestore.instance.document('/staff/'+sender).get();
      senderNameKey = 'senderName';
      senderName = snappy['name'];
      print('Doc for sender' + senderName);
      senderPicKey = 'senderPic';
      senderPic =  snappy['profilePic'];
      senderSpecKey = 'specialization';
      senderSpec = snappy['specialization'];

      fullMessage = <String, dynamic> {
      senderKey: sender,
      senderNameKey: senderName,
      senderSpecKey: senderSpec,
      senderPicKey: senderPic,
      timeKey: time,
      msgBodyKey: msgBody,};

      messages.add(fullMessage);
  }

  return messages;


}
```